# Reason max() returns a different result for an array with same elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, comparison

Is there a good explanation why the `max()` function returns a different result given two arrays below (with the same elements, different ordering)?
Possibly, just the fact it returns the first instance of "max" value which appears after the argument is evaluated?

```py
>>> max([1, False, 0, True])  # returns 1
>>> max([True, False, 0, 1])  # returns True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Value returned by max depends on first value of list:

```
print(max([True, 1]))# will return True
print(max([1, True]))# will return 1
```

You can use:

```
print(bool(max(1, True)))# will return True
print(bool(max(True, 1)))# also return True

print(int(max(True, 1)))# will return 1
print(int(max(1, True)))# also return 1
```

Edit:

The usage of for example `bool(x: int)` will convert integer `x` to boolean value, and `int(y: bool)` will convert boolean value `y` to  integer.

With use of this we can ensure what will the `max()` function return.

Comment: This was my notion as well and I'd accept it as an answer if you can provide a canonical explanation.

Comment: Well, if even this didint help you can lookup why max() works like this in [its definition](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/bltinmodule.c#min_max).

Answer (score -1):

first line: since first value is int it's an int array

second line:since first value is bool it's a bool array

- True <=> 1
- False <=> 0
- (could also be the other way around)

Comment: There are no "int arrays" or "bool arrays" in Python. Both are lists, which can contain arbitrary objects.

Comment: The max function determens the return type based on the first element. That's why wenn a Bool like `True` is first it will return a a Bool and when first element is int it will return an int.

Comment: What does `max([True, 2])` return?

Comment: 2, because 2 can't be convert to a bool and therefor need to handle the list as numbers

Comment: And what does `max([False, 1])` return?

Comment: oke i see my flaw :D. So it's determined by the highest value?